# Python getting a specific numeric values from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which looks like that (it is just an example, it has more that 1k lines):

```
},
series: [{x:1585937577000,y:0.1000},{x:1585937757000,y:0.1000},{x:1585937937000,y:0.1000},{x:1585938117000,y:0.0800},{x:1585938297000,y:0.0800},{x:1585938478000,y:0.0600},{x:1585939739000,y:0.0200},{x:1585939919000,y:0.0200},{x:1585940099000,y:0.0000}],
                yAxis: 0,
                color: "rgba(80,180,50,1)",
```

I am interested only in information in dictionaries, I want to get a list of x values and second list of y values, only that, rest is garbage. Just values without key.
I've tried some regex like:

```
x:(.*)\,
x:\.(.*?),
x:\.(.*?),y:
```

However it doesn't work, propably beacuse there are no white spaces between. I am confused with any further ideas, is there easy way to do this?

Comment: Why did you add a literal dot `\.` here: `x:\.(.*?),`? None of the values of `x` start with a dot, and it seems to work if you remove it: https://regex101.com/r/My4snv/1

Comment: Yay it solved problem, thanks bro. I always do something stupid while using regex

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what the overall structure of your data is, however if it is a list or dict of dicts on the form in your example, you could do a literal eval with the `ast` module and loop over the data. Note that if it is a dict of dicts, you should change the loops accordingly.

```py
import ast

d = "[{'series': [{'x':1585937577000,'y':0.1000},{'x':1585937757000,'y':0.1000}," \
    "{'x':1585937937000,'y':0.1000},{'x':1585938117000,'y':0.0800}," \
    "{'x':1585938297000,'y':0.0800},{'x':1585938478000,'y':0.0600}," \
    "{'x':1585939739000,'y':0.0200},{'x':1585939919000,'y':0.0200}," \
    "{'x':1585940099000,'y':0.0000}], 'yAxis': 0, 'color': 'rgba(80,180,50,1)'}]"

d = ast.literal_eval(d)

x = [x['x'] for val in d for x in val['series']]
y = [x['y'] for val in d for x in val['series']]
```

Output:

```py
x = [1585937577000, 1585937757000, 1585937937000, 1585938117000, 1585938297000, 1585938478000, 1585939739000, 1585939919000, 1585940099000]
y = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.02, 0.02, 0.0]
```